# Using Schwarz Reflection principle and Identity principle to show that a mapping vanishes.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am reading a solution to the following problem:

Suppose $f(z)$ is analytic on the unit disk $D(0,1)$ and continuous on the closed unit disk. Assume that $f(z)=0$ on an arc of the circle $z=1$. Show that $f(z)=0$.

We first define $h(z)= \frac{z-i}{z+i}$ which is a conformal mapping from the half-plane to the unit disk. The define $g = f \circ h$ so that $g$ is an analytic mapping from the half-plane to the unit disk that is continuous on $\mathbb{H} \cup \mathbb{R}$ and sends some interval of $\mathbb{R}$ to zero. (I think this is true because $h$ must send the boundary of $\mathbb{H}$ to the boundary of the unit disk). Now let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{H}$ whose closure will intersect $\mathbb{R}$ in some interval $I$. Let $U'$ be the reflection of $U$ across the real line. Then there exists a holomorphic extension $G: U \cup I \cup U' \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $G \vert_U = g$.

The proof then goes on to state that via the identity principle $G=0$. However, to use the identity principles I would need to find a sequence of distinct points in $U \cup I \cup U'$ with accumulation point in $U \cup I \cup U'$ so that $G$ evaluated at each of these points is equal to zero.

Why does such a sequence exist in this case?

Comment: Hint: $I$ is not arbitrary. You are able to choose it in such a way as to guarantee the existence of such a sequence.

Comment: Ok. For the right choice of $I$, namely such that $h(I)$ is the arc of the circle which is sent to zero, I am still not seeing what sequence to use. We know that $g(I)=0$ but we only have the restriction on $U$.

Comment: You now have a holomorphic function on a domain which contains $I$, so it must be 0. But $g$ is the restriction of that function to $U$ which yields the fact that $g$ is also zero on $\mathbb{H}$

Comment: I'm sorry but I just don't see why a holomorphic function containing $I$ in the domain must be zero. I would believe that if $G \vert_{U \cup I} = g$ but that is not the case.

Comment: It's a holomorphic function in a domain containing $I$ that is $0$ on $I$!